# How is the "correct" way of doing this? Ellipsis, handler

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ellipsis

What I am looking for : Selecting all my **Spans** in a **Container**, and seeing wether they are **ellipsed**(*text ellipsis*) or not, to add a tooltip.

Can't use: **Jquery**,

I am using **React**, and **ES6** , however this, should be a purely JS issue, this is my current approach, thank you very much for your help.

My current approach:

```
  isElipsed(element){
    return (element.scrollHeight > (element.innerHeight() + 1) || element.scrollWidth > (element.innerHeight() + 1))
}

isEllipsisActive() {
    let valuesArray = document.getElementsByClassName("operation-information__value");
    function eventAdder(){
        addEventListener("mouseover",function ( event ) {
            console.log(arguments);
            if(this.isElipsed(event.target)){
                event.target.className += ' asdasd';
            }
            else {}
        }
    }

    valuesArray.forEach(this.eventAdder)
}
```

Comment: Have you ellipsed it yourself, I mean simulated or have you used css property to ellipse the text?

Comment: _“My current approach:”_ - and with that what happens exactly …?

Comment: it doesn't compiles, to begin with, I ve seen other people do it with Jquery similarly , I am pretty sure, this should be working but it must be sintactically wrong

Comment: @Aditya I used CSS

Comment: @Marcos, I am still not clear, where are you stuck exactly?

Does isElipsed() works for you correctly? Or you want to identify the element isElipsed or not